# i need to render the element <AddProduct /> inside main-content div in another component (Dashboard)

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header/Header';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route ,Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import Pages from './Pages/Pages';
import Data from "./Components/FlashDeals/Data"
import Cart from './Components/Cart/Cart';
import Sdata from './Components/Shop/Sdata'; 
import {auth} from "../src/Firebase/Firebase"
import Dashboard from './Admin/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import AdminMain from './Admin/AdminMain/AdminMain';
import AddProduct from './Admin/AddProduct/AddProduct';


function App() {
  const  productItems = Data.productItems
  const {shopItems} = Sdata
  const [cartItem,setCartItem] = useState([]);
  const [userData,setUserData] = useState(undefined);
  const [adminRoute,setAdminRoute] = useState(false)

  console.log(adminRoute)

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(window.location.pathname.startsWith('/admin')){
      setAdminRoute(true)
    }else{
      setAdminRoute(false)
    }
  },[])


  
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user && user.emailVerified) {
        console.log("user is",user)
        setUserData(user)
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const handleSignOut = () => {
    auth.signOut()
      .then(() => {
        setUserData(undefined);
        setCartItem([]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Sign out error:', error);
      });
  };


  const addToCart = (product)=>{
    const productExit = cartItem.find((item)=>item.id === product.id)
    if(productExit){
      setCartItem(cartItem.map((item)=>
        (item.id === product.id ? {...productExit,qty:productExit.qty + 1} : item)
      ))
    }else{
      setCartItem([...cartItem,{...product,qty:1}])
    }
  }

  const decreaseQty = (product) =>{
    const productExit = cartItem.find((item)=>item.id === product.id)
    if(productExit.qty === 1){
      setCartItem(cartItem.filter((item)=>item.id !== product.id))
    }else{
      setCartItem(cartItem.map((item)=>(item.id=== product.id ? {...productExit,qty : productExit.qty-1}:item)))
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        {adminRoute ? <Dashboard/>  : <Header cartItem={cartItem} userData={userData} handleSignOut={handleSignOut}/> }
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Pages productItems={productItems} addToCart={addToCart} cartItem={cartItem} shopItems={shopItems} userData={userData} />}/>
          <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart cartItem={cartItem} addToCart={addToCart} decreaseQty={decreaseQty}/>}/>
          <Route path='/admin/dashboard' element={<AdminMain/>}/>
          <Route path='/admin/add-product' element={<AddProduct />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is my App.js and what i want is to  render the element <AddProduct /> inside .main-content div in Dashboard component.

Daashboard component is

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import AdminSidebar from '../AdminSidebar/AdminSidebar'
import AdminHeader from '../AdminHeader/AdminHeader';
import "./Dashboard.css"

function Dashboard() {
  const [checkboxChecked, setCheckboxChecked] = useState(false);
  const handleCheckboxChange = (event) => {
    console.log("working")
    const sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
    const mainContent = document.querySelector(".main-content");
  
    if (sidebar && mainContent) {
      sidebar.style.left = event.target.checked ? "-100%" : "0";
      mainContent.style.marginLeft = event.target.checked ? "0" : "";
      const mainContentHeader = mainContent.querySelector("header");
      if (mainContentHeader) {
        mainContentHeader.style.left = event.target.checked ? "0" : "";
        mainContentHeader.style.width = event.target.checked ? "100%" : "";
        mainContentHeader.style.right = event.target.checked ? "0" : "";
      }
    }
  };

  const handleToggleClick = () => {
    setCheckboxChecked(!checkboxChecked);
    handleCheckboxChange({ target: { checked: !checkboxChecked } });
  };
  

  return (
    <>
      <AdminSidebar/>
      <div className='main-content'>
        <AdminHeader handleToggleClick={handleToggleClick}/>
      </div>
      
      <input type="checkbox" name='' id='sidebar-toggle' onChange={handleCheckboxChange} checked={checkboxChecked}/>
      <label htmlFor="sidebar-toggle" className='body-label' onClick={handleToggleClick}></label>
    </>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

is there any way to do this . i am not interested in conditional rendering . i am expecting a good solution
please help me if anyone can. I tried outlet and others but didnt work.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Why not just import the component into `Dashboard` and have it part of its render? If that's not feasible you need to give us more details about the actual problem you're facing.

Comment: if i do like this then i need to do the same to some other components also . the dashboard is constant and i need to render the other components as per the routes . but the components should be rendered inside the <div className='main-content'> div

Answer (score 1):

Dashboard :

```html
      <div className='main-content'>
        <AdminHeader handleToggleClick={handleToggleClick} />
        <Outlet /> {/* Render nested routes */}
      </div>
```

App :

```html
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Pages productItems={productItems} addToCart={addToCart} cartItem={cartItem} shopItems={shopItems} userData={userData} />} />
          <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart cartItem={cartItem} addToCart={addToCart} decreaseQty={decreaseQty} />} />
          <Route path='/admin/*' element={<Dashboard />}>
            <Route path='dashboard' element={<AdminMain />} />
            <Route path='add-product' element={<AddProduct />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
```

Comment: this not working its not rendering inside .main-content div